# Rust cross compile target to android platform `x86_64-linux-android` and `aarch64-linux-android`

Tags: android, rust, linker

How to setup/config Rust linker for Android target. Google's Android NDK already installed, and set linker for

```
[target.x86_64-linux-android]
linker = "x86_64-linux-android34-clang"

[target.aarch64-linux-android]
linker = "aarch64-linux-android34-clang"
```

got: `clang: No such file or directory`.

What is the right linker configuration?